Puppeteer - Can I persisting loged in session when transfer to other computer?
I have used "userDataDir" to store browser data to my local machine, but when I used this stored data on other computer, the target site ask me to login again.
Is it possible to store and reuse browser data between other machine (without be asking to login again)

I don't see why it shouldn't work in general, although maybe the site is doing some server-side detection. Please share the site, a package.json and your code so this is reproducible. Thanks.
